# A more efficient way of extracting data from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have messages coming in from a chat client that I want to parse for a # sign and then extract 1-3 digits after it plus a letter after the numbers. Since I dont know if the number will be 1, 2 or 3 digits long I test each as an integer and then assign the variables. I came up with the following code but my programming skills are very basic...

```
var test = 'it doesnt matter how long the message is I only need #222c';
var QuID = '';
var Qans = '';
var regInteger = /^\d+$/;


//this function checks to see if a charactor is an integer
function isInteger( str ) {    
    return regInteger.test( str );
}

var IDloc = test.indexOf('#') + 1;
var IDloc2 = test.indexOf('#') + 2
console.log(IDloc);

//This is a brute force method to test if there is a 1-3 digit number and assigning the question number and question answer into variables. Sloppy but it's duct tape and wire programming my friend!
if(isInteger(test.substring(IDloc, IDloc2))) {
   QuID = (test.substring(IDloc, IDloc2));
   Qans = (test.substring((IDloc + 1), (IDloc2 + 1)));
    if (isInteger(test.substring((IDloc +1), (IDloc2 + 1)))) {
        QuID = (test.substring(IDloc, (IDloc2 + 1)));
        Qans = (test.substring((IDloc + 2), (IDloc2+ 3)));
            if (isInteger(test.substring((IDloc + 2), (IDloc2 + 2)))) {
                QuID = (test.substring(IDloc, (IDloc2 + 2)));
                Qans = (test.substring((IDloc + 3), (IDloc2 + 4)));
            }
    }

   console.log( QuID );
   console.log( Qans );
} else {
   console.log( 'Non Integer' );
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to code this as I feel it is a brute force method.

Comment: Use your regex to extract values using group matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = test.match(/#(\d{1,3})([a-zA-Z])/);
if (result) {
    var numbers = result[1];
    var character = result[2];
}
```

This extracts 1-3 digits (after a # sign) followed by one character (in the range from a-z lower and uppercase, if you need any special character such as äüß you'd need to add them) into two different capture groups and then reads those capture groups into two variables. Note that this only extracts the first match.

Answer (score 2):

You could search for `#` and take the numbers behind.

```js
var getNumber = s => (s.match(/#(\d+)/) || [])[1];
    
console.log(getNumber('it doesnt matter how long the message is I only need #222c'));
console.log(getNumber('foo'));
console.log(getNumber('fo2o'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = 'it doesnt matter how long the message is I only need #222c';
var result=0;
(test.split("#")[1]||"").split("").every(char=>parseInt(char,10)&&(result=result*10+ +char));
console.log(result);
```

just a non regex answer...